# Existence of linear stochastic differential equation given solution

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, existence-theorems

Normally if you have a linear SDE given such as
$dx_t = (A(t)x_t + a(t))dt + \sigma(t) dW_t$, we want to find $x_t$, more precisely we want to find the mean and variance of $x_t$ at each timestep $t$. When the functions are measurable, continuous, locally bounded and real-valued 1-dimensional, then $x_t$ can be computed. We assume in the following that $x_t$ is (Gaussian) normal distributed.

I want to do the opposite: Given $f$, mean $m(t)$ and a variance $v(t)$ can I compute the diffusion term from it, so that I can write down the SDE that has a solution with given mean and variance ?

My approach: The variance of a SDE must satisfy:
$v'(t) = 2A(t)v(t) + \sigma(t)^2$. So we can compute from this $\sigma(t)$:
$\sigma(t) = \sqrt{v'(t) - 2A(t)v(t)}$ and I conclude from this that $v'(t) - 2A(t)v(t)>0$, otherwise we cannot take the root?
This means that it can happen for a bad choice of the mean (or A(t)) and variance, that I cannot compute the diffusion term from it, is that correct?
Moreover, why can't I take the complex root $\sqrt{v'(t) - 2A(t)v(t)}$ if $v'(t) - 2A(t)v(t)$ is negative? Such a $\sigma(t)$ is discontinuous in the complex plane and obviously not real-valued. But such a $\sigma(t)$ also allows to construct me the desired SDE?

Answer (score 0):

Existence was shown a long time ago eg.  article ["Mimicking the One-Dimensional Marginal Distributions of Processes Having an Ito Differential"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00699039). As mentioned [here](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/when-does-the-mean-and-variance-define-an-sde/), uniqueness seems to be a research question, which is surprising to me.

My guess is that there can be multiple SDEs with same mean and variance. In that article they do talk about uniqueness in the case of smooth variance. I would go through the articles that cited for possibly more recent results eg. ["Mimicking an Itô process by a solution of a stochastic differential equation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0111#:%7E:text=Mimicking%20an%20It%C3%B4%20process%20by%20a%20solution%20of%20a%20stochastic%20differential%20equation,-Gerard%20Brunick%2C%20Steven&text=Given%20a%20multi%2Ddimensional%20It%C3%B4,process%20at%20each%20fixed%20time.) where they go over this problem again.

Comment: If I understand  "Mimicking the One-Dimensional Marginal Distributions of Processes Having an Ito Differential" correctly, then we assume that there exists a stochastic process with ito differential as in the very first two lines of that pdf file. But I dont know how to construct this process in the first place when my mean and variance are given. Can someone help me out with that?

Comment: these are the drift and volatility coefficient respectively. $$\xi(t)=\int^t m'_{s}ds+\int^t \sigma'_{s}dWs$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still don't understand. If $m(t)$ is the mean then I would know how to get the drift coefficient from it. If $v(t)$ is the variance, what is now your $\sigma(t)`$ ? How do you compute that ?

Comment: sorry, the right thing is $\sqrt{\sigma'(t)}$. So when we compute second moment, by Ito isometry we get $\int^{t}\sigma'(s)ds=\sigma(t)$.

Comment: That confuses me even more:
First with $\sigma'(t)$ you are referring to the derivative of the variance $\sigma(t)$?
Second, it is obvious to me that then $\int \sigma'(s) ds = \sigma(t)$ (fundamental 
theorem of calculus).
Third, if what you call volatility coefficient is given I must compute the conditioned expectation: $E[\delta(t) \delta(t)| \xi_t = x ]$, where $\delta$ is the volatility coefficient from the paper, and I dont know what it means. I tried to find examples of the aforementioned scipts but there were no examples of how to compute this expectation.

Comment: That is something different; perhaps I misused terms. Alll I am just saying that if you start with differentiable mean  and variance
$$m(t):=E[\xi(t)]$$ and $$\sigma(t):=E[\xi^{2}(t)]$$, 
then the process $\xi(t)=\mu(t)+\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\sigma'(s)}dW_{s}$ is a linear Ito diffusion with those mean and variance.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying this up. But what I say is then that the taking the root of the derivative of the variance might be complex valued. What if the variance is first increasing and then decreasing at some point? Then you cannot simply take the root. For instance, Brownian bridge do have such a variance. This is prescisely where I'm stuck at.

Comment: well then even simpler, just consider $$\xi(t)=m(t)+\sqrt{\frac{\sigma(t)}{t}}B_{t}$$ for the case of non-positive derivative $\sigma'$. However, if you also want a  specific covariance $\sigma(s,t):=E[\xi(s)\xi(t)]$, then it is more tricky but we can try in a new question.